# Facing issue to get updated result by using "TI Wishlist" wordpress plugin API in IONIC

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework

I am using "TI Wishlist" plugin in my wordpress >> woocommerce site to add / remove product in wish-list.

The plugin offers API that i am using in my ionic application to add / remove product from wish list.

But when i add / delete product, many time it happens that product not displays immediately after adding it to wish-list. After sometime it automatically displays it in my wish-list screen.

By removing it from wish-list it actually deleted by calling API of it but still gives result in my listing screen. After sometime it removes from wish-list also.

What i am doing wrong ?